# Deleted iCloud contacts keep coming back

Tags: icloud, contacts

Tried to delete several contacts on iCloud.com, but they keep coming back! I have tried several times with no success.

These contacts are still on my device with iCloud sync enabled.

If I don't want to disable iCloud sync do I have to remove these contacts on the devices as well?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before. After some experiment, here is what I have found working:

Go to Setting > Mail,Contacts,Calendars > Fetch New Data > iCloud > Select "Push" (if you select "Fetch", the iPhone changes will supersede changes made on iCloud. It is up to individual preference)

After "Push" is selected, you may make all the changes you want to iCloud Contacts. Your iPhone will be updated in the next Sync.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud is a way to keep the same data accessible via all your Apple devices.

It isn't set-up to allow you to keep different data on different devices.  If it were, then what would be the point of the service?

They're appearing in iCloud repeatedly because you have sync turned on.

However, you can disable **just** the syncing of contacts by going to Settings -> iCloud -> Switch Contacts to OFF.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The asker is trying to remove certain iCloud contacts from all of their devices. They would like to keep the data the same across the web and their device, but when they delete the contacts, they continue to reappear. What they would like to know is how to stop these contacts from reappearing.

Comment: exactly @timothymh! thx for the explanation

Comment: I think the issue is still unclear to me.  Do you want these several contacts removed from ALL your devices, and the web version of iCloud?

Comment: Yeah thats right and am looking for some sort of a central control to do that

Answer (score 1):

These contacts are most probably stored not only in iCloud, but also on your device separately, in the device-only contact group called "on my iPhone".

Your situation is probably a remnant of the times when you synced the contacts via iTunes. Then they got migrated to iCloud and were effectively doubled, but you only saw one contact in the Contacts app, because your iPhone (or iPad) displayed only one entry when contacts were doubled like that.

What you need to do is go to the Contacts app, touch "groups" and turn off the iCloud group(s), but leave the group "on my iPhone". Then you will be able to ultimately delete the contacts that were there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set your (possible) iPhone / iPad / iPod Touch onto airplane mode, and then doing the change from the http://icloud.com with your log-in, deleting specific contacts, then waiting for a couple of minutes and bringing the devices back from airplane mode and then checking what the status is in them and on the iCloud?